# Comparing with a private interface

Tags: go, interface, comparison

I have two objects. `key1` is of type `*rsa.PublicKey`. `key2` is of type `*ssh.PublicKey` which is an interface hiding a `*ssh.rsaPublicKey` object. `ssh.rsaPublicKey` is defined as:

```
type ssh.rsaPublicKey rsa.PublicKey
```

And it has a few extra methods. However, I can't cast either key to an `ssh.rsaPublicKey` since that class is "not exported", I can't cast `key2` to an `rsa.PublicKey` since that doesn't implement `ssh.PublicKey`, and I can't access the `N` or `e` from `key2` because I am not supposed to know I have an `rsaPublicKey` object.

How am I supposed to compare that `key1` and `key2` are the same key?

Comment: For staters what's your definition of equality? I would guess there is some way to get at the data or do a conversion.

Comment: My definition of equality is "same modulus, same `N`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can't use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) because you can't refer to the unexported type `ssh.rsaPublicKey`.

What you want is possible with using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package.

Since `rsa.PublicKey` is the underlying type of `ssh.rsaPublicKey`, the *pointed* value wrapped in `key2` can be converted to `rsa.PublicKey`. Once you obtain [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) of your `key2`, "navigate" to the *pointed* value using [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem). This value is convertible to a value of type `rsa.PublicKey`. You may use the [`Value.Convert()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert) to "dynamically", at runtime convert it to `rsa.PublicKey`. Once you have it, you can use [`reflect.DeepEquals()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) to do the comparison, or compare it manually.

This is how it could look like:

```
key1 := &rsa.PublicKey{N: big.NewInt(123), E: 10}
key2, _ := ssh.NewPublicKey(&rsa.PublicKey{N: big.NewInt(123), E: 10})


key2conv := reflect.ValueOf(key2).Elem().
    Convert(reflect.TypeOf(rsa.PublicKey{})).Interface()
// key2conf is an interface{}, wrapping an rsa.PublicKey

// Comparision with DeepEqual
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(*key1, key2conv))

// Comparing manually:
key22 := key2conv.(rsa.PublicKey)
fmt.Println(key1.N.Cmp(key22.N)) // Int.Cmp() returns 0 if equal
fmt.Println(key1.E == key22.E)
```

Note that when comparing manually, comparing the `PublicKey.N` field –which is of type `*big.Int`– you need to use the [`Int.Cmp()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Cmp) method because comparing pointers compares the memory addresses, not the pointed values. And `Int.Cmp()` returns `0` if the 2 values are equal.