# How to test an interface variable's underlying type if the interface variable's type is an alias

Tags: go, types, interface

Golang newbie here.

The short version of this question is: given an interface value which could be of an aliased type, what's the proper way to check whether it is of an underlying type?

I found that type assertion and type switch doesn't work.

For example, in the following program, I have a bunch of automatically generated named types `Alias<N>` from an underlying type `Origin`. And I have an interface variable `v`, which could be of any type. I'd like to use its `Field` value if `v` is of type `Origin`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Origin struct {
    Field int
}

type Alias1 Origin
type Alias2 Origin
type Alias3 Origin

// A bunch of other aliases

func f(v interface{}) {
    if _, ok := v.(Origin); ok {
        fmt.Println("type assertion works")
    }

    switch v := v.(type) {
    case Origin:
        fmt.Println("type switch works")
    case Alias1:
        fmt.Printf("No... Alias1 Value: %v\n", v.Field)
    case Alias2:
        fmt.Printf("No... Alias2 Value: %v\n", v.Field)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("No... Alias3 Value: %T\n", v.(Origin).Field)
    }
}

func main() {
    f(Alias1{Field: 10})
    f(Alias2{Field: 10})
    f(Alias3{Field: 10})
}
```

Output as shown in https://play.golang.org/p/3WjpX6NcfF:

```
No... Alias1 Value: 10
No... Alias2 Value: 10
panic: interface conversion: interface is main.Alias3, not main.Origin
```

What would be the correct way? (I cannot list all aliased types of `Origin` in `f` since those aliased types are automatically generated and scattered around.) Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**===== Edit 1 =====**

Tried to use the `reflect` package, but still don't have the solution: https://play.golang.org/p/3LtG9ZOkQd

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Origin struct {
    Field int
}

type Alias1 Origin

// A bunch of other aliases

func g(v interface{}) {
    vt := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    ot := reflect.TypeOf(Origin{})
    if vt.ConvertibleTo(ot) {
        fmt.Printf("%T is convertible to Origin", v)

        // panic: interface is main.Alias3, not main.Origin
        // fmt.Printf("Value: %v\n", v.(Origin).Field)

        // error: vt is not a type
        // fmt.Printf("Value: %v\n", v.(vt).Field)

        // error: cannot convert v (type interface {}) to type Origin: need type assertion
        // fmt.Printf("Value: %v\n", Origin(v).Field)

    }
}

func main() {
    g(Alias1{Field: 10})
}
```

Comment: just thought - may be compare field by field? field sets of both orig and alias types seems equal https://play.golang.org/p/TY5eMrN4m9

Comment: @shibormot Hmm, that seems doesn't really help since I still cannot "use" `v` (an interface value) as a `Origin` type. The compiler doesn't allow me to cast `v` to `Origin` even if `v`'s type has the same fields as `Origin`.

Comment: reflect.ValueOf and reflect.Convert are your friends https://play.golang.org/p/dspem2VnA7

Comment: but what you are trying to achive makes little sense. Looks like you want to add behavior to your structs and "aliases" - define interface with GetField and SetField methods.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Comparing with a private interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024562/comparing-with-a-private-interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest I can get is this:

```
fmt.Printf("Value: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(v).Convert(ot).Interface().(Origin).Field)
```

(instead of third fmt in your code)

It converts v to origin type using reflection. But then to use type assertion, but that will be reflect.Value. To cast it to type Origin, it needs to be converted to interface{} and then it can be type asserted to Origin type.

Comment: Cool! This is what I've been looking for! Actually just several scroll down away from what I've already tried. Thanks anyway!